# save data Yii many to many

Tags: php, yii

I've already read a lot of info but I can't understand how can I get actor id from checkBoxList. I have tables actors, connect, films with many to many. Everything almost ok, in `$_POST` after click save in form, there is:

```
array (size=3)

  'Film' => 
    array (size=2)
      'name' => string 'bvb' (length=3)
      'about' => string 'fdgg' (length=4)
  'Actors' => 
    array (size=1)
      'id' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string '2' (length=1)
  'yt0' => string 'Create' (length=6)
```

So i tried to put  my `$_POST['Actors']['id']` to the connect table, but nothing happen:

```
protected function afterSave(){
    $actors=$this->ActorsArray;
    parent::afterSave();
    $postCat = new Connect();
    $postCat->id_film = $this->id;
    if (isset($_POST['Actors'])){
    $postCat->id_actor = $_POST['Actors']}
    $postCat->save();
}
```

this is from film controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Film;
    $model1=new Actors();
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
    if(isset($_POST['Film']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Film'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,'model1'=>$model1,
    ));
}
```

Comment: It's really bad practice to put env variable, such as $_POST, into data models. To solve your problem try to get errors: `var_dump($postCat->getErrors())`

Comment: I just start today to learn Yii, where I should look at this errors. It doesn't shaw me var_dump from aftersave function

Comment: You should put this `var_dump()` after `$postCat->save();`

Comment: It doesn't show anything

Comment: Than your `afterSave` function is not fired

Comment: Is this action called via ajax?

Comment: I find one error, I erase model->save from controller function. But it still didn't work

Comment: You should somehow get the result of `$postCat->getErrors()`. If you call your action via ajax, you can see the output in browser console (or firebug console).

Comment: I edit my post. If I put just value of actor id, it's work fine, but don't work with my $_Post

Comment: Your `$_POST['Actors']['id']` is an array

Comment: Maybe your way is to use `$_POST['Actors']['id'][0]` instead?